# PyCharm SSH tunneling via local ssh config (~/.ssh/config)

Tags: python, deployment, configuration, ssh, pycharm

I use ssh deployment on servers via ssh tunnels, 
and each of its has specific options and port forwarding placed in *~/.ssh/config*.

PyCharm uses by default its own ssh client when using SFTP deploy.
So, it doesn't work with these deployment servers.
How I could force PyCharm to use my default system ssh client or force to use options from *~/.ssh/config* file.
Thanks.

PS: PyCharm version is 3.0.1

Comment: So, I sent request to JetBrains support about that, and unfortunately there is no way to do that...
Will waiting for this feature.
Tracking [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/requests/13815)

Comment: Could you post anonymized ~/.ssh/config in question?

Comment: @skybobbi I get a 404 on that tracking page, even after login. Is it private?

Answer (score 2):

Provided PyCharm can be made to use port different than 22 (don't know that), you actually have two workarounds:

- Simple workaround

Use port forwarding on localhost:

http://www.debian-administration.org/article/449/SSH_dynamic_port_forwarding_with_SOCKS

..and either use `-F specific_config` for each tunnel, or use `-o` to specify relevant options (that you normally have in `~/.ssh/config` on `ssh` commandline) directly. Of course, you have to tell PyCharm to connect to `localhost:forwarded_port`.

- Fancy/sophisticated workaround

Use dynamic port forwarding + `tsocks`, again described in:

http://www.debian-administration.org/article/449/SSH_dynamic_port_forwarding_with_SOCKS

Comment: PyCharm can indeed be told to connect to different port. However, I can't get the tunnel to work. Would you please post a bit more information on how this can be achieved